# Git conflicts when rebasing on squashed code

Tags: git, github

I will try to explain the issue as I understand and as easily as possible.

So as a base branch, I am using another branch (non-master) which includes changes that I need.

But when the base branch is merged to master and when I want to rebase with master I face 40+ steps `git rebase --continue` and most of the files are the same which appears after the `--continue` command. for example, the exact file with the exact conflict appears after 1 or 2 `--continue` commands again. And those are the lines that I don't touch.

What I think is the reason why it shows up is because on master it is squashed but in my code, those are in separate commits. But still, it doesn't explain to me why I am getting the same conflict file over and over again.

Does `git rebase --skip` for all 40+ okay to run or I should manually update all of them to choose `current changes`? because the code on the master show as `current` in conflict.

What is the best way to deal with that kind of conflict?

I see a log of posts about `--skip` but they don't answer my questions. I am a bit afraid of what if skip will skip the actual commit coming from the master and will not be visible in the diff, and when I merge the branch to the master it will delete the commit and code from the master branch.

On the title it might not be super helpful to understand so I you suggest I can change it according.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `rerere`. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere

Answer (score 1):

This is an unfortunate side effect of squash merge: information about what commits got merged is not kept in git alone.

You can rebase your work by spotting what part of your history needs rebasing :

- in the history of your branch, spot what commit got merged into master
- write down the `<sha>` of that commit
- run `git rebase --onto master <sha> my-branch`

Answer (score -2):

What I did is creating a new branch and do cherry-pick to copy old commits from then branch which had issues on rebase. seams it worked as expected

Comment: Makes no sense because rebase and cherry-pick are the same thing. Unless you show us the actual commands you gave to Git and what Git replied to you, both in the question and in the answer, this entire QA pair is pretty much useless.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't understand what you mean. so why I cherry-pick because I don't have any files that I touch which can cause a conflict neither on the master nor base branch. So I create a new branch from the master and instead of copying files manually I pick the commits from my feature branch and put them to a new branch. what would I make wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what _you_ mean. I think the key here might be my request "show us the actual commands you gave to Git and what Git replied to you". Until you have done that, it's impossible to know what you were doing before and what you are doing now. In general on Stack Overflow, the rule of thumb is: don't talk _about_ code; _show_ code.

Comment: @matt : my guess is that, instead of running a complete `rebase` which would replay the commits squashed by the PR, the OP was able to cherry-pick the relevant commits (the ones *after* the PR) on top of his branch. It is a valid alternative to `git rebase --onto <target> <base> my-branch`

Comment: Could be! But this answer doesn't say that. And if true it's effectively identical to your answer.

Comment: yes, LeGec is correct I am sorry if I can't explain it. So what I did is just create a new branch from the master and from my feature branch, I picked my file changes and apply them to the new branch which will include only the master code (and the squash commit from my old base branch) and my changed files. So I still had a clean history and commits that I need (the files only I changed did not exist anywhere else without conflict). So yes I skipped the `rebase`